# Angularjs returnJson from database

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to return a JSON Object in a datatable. I've provided the static working code that I found in an example in my angularjs template.
Thanks for help.

controller.js

```
function datatablesCtrl($scope,DTOptionsBuilder){
    $scope.persons = [
        {
            id: '1',
            firstName: 'Monica',
            lastName: 'Smith'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            firstName: 'Sandra',
            lastName: 'Jackson'
        }
    ];
}
```

Utenti.jsp

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight" ng-controller="datatablesCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
           <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
               <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>FirstName</th>
                   <th>LastName</th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
                   <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
                   <td>{{ person.user }}</td>
                   <td>{{ person.password }}</td>
               </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to populate the $scope.person with data into a database.
The table of database is "utenti" with column id,fistName,lastName.

These are my classes.. There is also a class Utenti with a simple getter & setter.

UtentiService.class

```
@Service("UtentiService")
public class UtentiService  implements IUtentiService{
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Utenti> getAll() {
        Query queryFindAll = null;
        try{
            queryFindAll = entityManager.createNamedQuery("utenti.findAll");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            logger.error("Failed in method **getAll** of utentiService: ",ex);
        }
        return (List)queryFindAll.getResultList();
    }
}
```

IUtentiService.class

```
public interface IUtentiService {
    public List<Utenti> getAll();   //Restituisce una lista di tutti i siti
}
```

UtentiRest.class

```
@Path("/utenti")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class UtentiRest {   
     @Autowired
     IUtentiService nameUtentiService;
     final static Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();   
     @GET
     @Produces("application/json")
     @Path("/getAll")
     public JSONObject getAll() {     
         ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
         JSONObject jsonSitiTotal = new JSONObject();
         try {
             List<Utenti> soluzioni = nameUtentiService.getAll();
             Iterator<Utenti> iter = soluzioni.iterator();
             JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
             while (iter.hasNext()) {
                 Utenti ut = (Utenti) iter.next();
                 JSONObject jsonSiti2 = new JSONObject();
                 jsonSiti2.put("id", ut.getId());
                 jsonSiti2.put("user", ut.getUserName());
                 jsonSiti2.put("password", ut.getPassword());
                 jsonArray.put(jsonSiti2);
             }
             jsonSitiTotal.put("Siti",jsonArray);
      } catch (JSONException ex) {
             logger.info(Level.ERROR, ex);
             throw new WebApplicationException(
                     Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                             .entity("JSON Exception " + ex.getMessage())
                             .build()
             );
         } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
             logger.info(Level.ERROR, ex);
             throw new WebApplicationException(
                     Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT)
                             .entity("No process find ")
                             .build()
             );
         } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
             logger.info(Level.ERROR, ex);
             throw new WebApplicationException(
                     Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                             .entity("Couldn't process request with the provided argument: "
                                     + " (" + ex.getMessage() + ")")
                             .build()
             );
         }finally {
             executorService.shutdown();
         }
         return  jsonSitiTotal;
     }
}
```

Comment: You will have to use an http call to get data from the server. try reading [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Don't show your full code anywhere for your security!